# Password dialog when using Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: remote-desktop, passwords, windows-server-2008

Sometimes when I connect to a Windows Server 2008 machine using Remote Desktop Connection a window pops up on my computer asking me to enter a username and password. Other times, I am connected to the server and that server then asks me to select which user I want to log on as (using it's GUI), and then to enter a password.

Why is that sometimes my computer (mstsc.exe) ask me to provide credentials to the remote machine, but at other times the remote server asks me to provide the credentials?

I prefer when my computer asks, since I can then copy-paste the password.

Answer (score 1):

The remote server only shows it when the details you provided are wrong, you're probably not properly copy pasting the password. Why not just memorize it and not have a problem with this security issue?

Comment: +1 - Definitely memorize the password.  If you're trying to make a password so cryptic that you have to copy and paste it from somewhere else, you're defeating the purpose.  It would be more secure to make one that's cryptic and memorable.

Comment: I'm downloading a .RDP file from the Windows Azure Management Portal. This file contains only the user name and load balancing info required to connect. We have *a lot* of different servers with different login details. They receive new passwords all the time and we don't manage all of them ourselves. How would I be able to memorize all those?

Comment: @trpt4him: Indeed, they designed public-key cryptography for this.